# Calculate how many months between two dates to define it is 6 months or over 6 months

Tags: lotus-formula

I have a lotus notes database. In a form there is a field called "ServiceDate" and another field called "ReadOrEdit".

The "ServiceDate" field I need to store in date so I use

```
@Date(@ThisValue)
```

to store the date properly.

Here is the scenario

If the ServiceDate is within 6 months, the ReadOrEdit field will show "Editable", if the ServiceDate is over 6 months, the ReadOrEdit field will show "ReadOnly". At that moment, the user does not define the exact 6 months yet so I assume six months have 186 (31 * 6) days roughly.

In "ReadOrEdit" field, I put the following code

```
SixMonths := 186;
date := @Now;
calculation := (@Date(date)-@Date(ServiceDate))/((60*60*24) + 1);
result := @If(calculation > SixMonths;"ReadOnly";"Editable");
@If(@IsError(result);"no result";result)
```

When I propose this approach to the user, the user rejects my approach. The user thinks I should not use days to define 6 months and 6 months should defined by month, for example, today is 01/03/2017, 6 months before that is 01/09/2016. If the date within 01/09/2016 to 01/03/2017, the ReadOrEdit Field should show "Editable". If the date is before 01/09/2016, the ReadOrEdit Field should show "ReadOnly".

This [website](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ADJUST.html) inspires me to use @Adjust in the ReadOrEdit field. I use the following code to try use @Adjust to find the date that is 6 months before the ServiceDate.

```
sixMonths :=@Date(@Adjust(ServiceDate;0;-6;0;0;0;0));
@If(@IsError(sixMonths);"no result";sixMonths)
```

When I run the program, if the input ServiceDate is 01/03/2017, the ReadOrEdit field will display 01/09/2016. Since the result same as the user requirement, I believe that I should use @Adjust in the program. The next thing I need to think is how to calculate how many months between today and the ServiceDate

I serach on the Internet there is not much information about calculate months between two dates. I think the code may be similar to my propose code so I begin to modify the code in order to fulfil the user reqirement.

Here is the code

```
today :=@Now;
sixMonths :=@Date(@Adjust(ServiceDate;0;-6;0;0;0;0));
sixMonthDays := @Abs(@Integer(( @Date(Today) -   @Date(ServiceDate) )));
calculation:=(@Date(today)-@Date(sixMonths));
result := @If(calculation > sixMonthDays;"ReadOnly";"Editable");
@If(@IsError(result);"no result";result)
```

When I run the program, I notice the result is not correct.

Here are my attemtps and the result only show "ReadOnly" no matter the date is within 6 months or the date is over 6 months.

If the input ServiceDate is 01/03/2017, it shows "ReadOnly"

If the input ServiceDate is 28/02/2017, it shows "ReadOnly"

If the input ServiceDate is 01/09/2016, it shows "ReadOnly"

If the input ServiceDate is 02/09/2016, it shows "ReadOnly"

If the input ServiceDate is 02/08/2016, it shows "ReadOnly"

If I change the code

```
result := @If(calculation > sixMonthDays;"ReadOnly";"Editable");
```

to

```
result := @If(calculation < sixMonthDays;"ReadOnly";"Editable");
```

the result is still not correct.

Here are my attemtps and the result only show "Editable" no matter the date is within 6 months or the date is over 6 months.

If the input ServiceDate is 01/03/2017, it shows "Editable"

If the input ServiceDate is 28/02/2017, it shows "Editable"

If the input ServiceDate is 01/09/2016, it shows "Editable"

If the input ServiceDate is 02/09/2016, it shows "Editable"

If the input ServiceDate is 02/08/2016, it shows "Editable"

Actually I think final result should be like this

If the input ServiceDate is 01/03/2017, "ReadOrEdit" field shows "Editable"

If the input ServiceDate is 28/02/2017, "ReadOrEdit" field shows "Editable"

If the input ServiceDate is 01/09/2016, "ReadOrEdit" field shows "Editable"

If the input ServiceDate is 02/09/2016, "ReadOrEdit" field shows "ReadOnly"

If the input ServiceDate is 02/08/2016, "ReadOrEdit" field shows "ReadOnly"

I revised the code and I thinks there are mistakes in the code but I do know in which part. I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262169/no-of-years-month-and-days) but I don't get the idea.

Grateful if someone let me know my mistakes or let me know how to calculate how many months between two dates(today and the ServiceDate) so that I can set whether it is Editable or ReadOnly please. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you, something is editable for six months after the service date?

You could just compare the dates directly.

`@If(@Adjust(ServiceDate; 0; 6; 0; 0; 0; 0) >= @Today; "Editable"; "ReadOnly")`

This assumes that ServiceDate is a date/time value.

This should return "Editable" if the ServiceDate was less than or exactly 6 months ago, and otherwise return "ReadOnly" if ServiceDate was more than 6 months ago. @Today is like @Now except it's a date-only value without the time of day.

Comment: Before I receive your answer, I am still thinking which part has mistake. Your answer is clear and helpful. Thank you very much.